# Collapsible side menu in Ionic2

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic2, ionic3

I want to create a side menu with collapsible content. Is there any example available out there that I could use as a reference? I've tried searching for the same but failed. Any help or pointer would be highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can take a look at [my github repo](https://github.com/sebaferreras/Ionic2-MultiLevelSideMenu). This is how the component looks like:

[image: side menu]

The README.md file explains clearly how to use it:

> Just copy the side-menu folder (inculding the html, ts and scss files)
>   in your project. Then include the SideMenuContentComponent in the
>   declarations array from your @NgModule.

Then in your `app.component.ts` file, create an array of options

```
public options: Array<MenuOptionModel>;
```

Where `MenuOptionModel` would be something like this:

```
let menuOption: MenuOptionModel = {
    iconName: 'ios-arrow-down',
    displayName: `Option Name`,
    component: PageName,
    isLogin: false,
    isLogout: false,
    subItems: [
        {
            iconName: 'ios-basket',
            displayName: `Sub Option 1`,
            component: PageName,
            isLogin: false,
            isLogout: false
        },
        {
            iconName: 'ios-bookmark',
            displayName: `Sub Option 2`,
            component: PageName,
            isLogin: false,
            isLogout: false
        }
    ]
};
```

and then just include it in the `app.component.html` file

```
<side-menu-content [options]="options"></side-menu-content>
```

There're a lot of improvements yet to be made in the repo, but you can take a look at the source code to get an idea of how everything is done (didn't add the code to the answer because it has ~250 lines of code).

Comment: Glad to help :)