# submenu in ion-side menu in ionic2

Tags: ionic2

How to add sub-menu in ion sidemenu? I have done following code for side menu

app.html

```
<ion-menu [content]="content">    
  <ion-header>    
    <ion-toolbar>    
      <ion-title>Menu</ion-title>    
    </ion-toolbar>    
  </ion-header>

  <ion-content>    
   <ion-list>    
      <button menuClose ion-item *ngFor="let p of pages" (click)="openPage(p)">    
        {{p.title}}    
      </button>    
    </ion-list>    
  </ion-content>    
</ion-menu>    

<ion-nav [root]="rootPage" #content swipeBackEnabled="false"></ion-nav>
```

app.compact.ts

```
import { Component ,ViewChild} from '@angular/core';    
import { Platform ,Nav} from 'ionic-angular';    
import { StatusBar } from '@ionic-native/status-bar';    
import { SplashScreen } from '@ionic-native/splash-screen';    
import { Dashboard } from '../pages/dashboard/dashboard';    
import { LineBoy } from '../pages/line-boy/line-boy';    
import { Customer } from '../pages/customer/customer';    
import { DeliveryLine } from '../pages/delivery-line/delivery-line';    
import { Newspaper } from '../pages/newspaper/newspaper';    
import { Scheme } from '../pages/scheme/scheme';    
import { Expenses } from '../pages/expenses/expenses';    
import { Report } from '../pages/report/report';    
import { Billing } from '../pages/billing/billing';    
import { Settings }from '../pages/settings/settings';

@Component({    
  templateUrl: 'app.html'    
})    
export class MyApp {

  rootPage:any = Dashboard;

  @ViewChild(Nav) nav: Nav;

  pages: Array<{title: string, component: any}>;

  constructor(platform: Platform, statusBar: StatusBar, splashScreen: SplashScreen) {

    platform.ready().then(() => {
      // Okay, so the platform is ready and our plugins are available.
      // Here you can do any higher level native things you might need.
      statusBar.styleDefault();
      splashScreen.hide();
    });

     this.pages = [
       { title: 'Dashboard', component: Dashboard },
       { title: 'LineBoy', component: LineBoy },
       { title: 'DeliveryLine', component: DeliveryLine },
       { title: 'Customer', component: Customer },
       { title: 'Newspaper', component: Newspaper },
       { title: 'Scheme', component: Scheme },
       { title: 'Expenses', component: Expenses },
       { title: 'Report', component: Report },
       { title: 'Billing', component: Billing },
       { title: 'Settings', component: Settings },
     ];
  }

  openPage(page) {        
    this.nav.setRoot(page.component);
  }

}
```

https://market.ionic.io/plugins/ionic-multilevel-sidemenu

Comment: please take a look at [this github repo](https://github.com/sebaferreras/Ionic2-MultiLevelSideMenu)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Collapsible side menu in Ionic2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43456126/collapsible-side-menu-in-ionic2)

Comment: @sebaferreras  thanks .....